# Why is 0 == ("abcde"+1) not a constant expression?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, language-lawyer, constexpr

Why doesn't the following code compile?

```
// source.cpp

int main()
{
   constexpr bool result = (0 == ("abcde"+1));
}
```

The compile command:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 -c source.cpp
```

The output:

```
source.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
source.cpp:4:32: error: ‘((((const char*)"abcde") + 1u) == 0u)’ is not a constant expression
 constexpr bool result = (0 == ("abcde"+1));
                         ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm using gcc6.4.

Comment: you just want to know why or is there some real use case? I mean you could write `constexpr bool result = false;` to get the same result

Comment: I want to know why because this code is extracted from a real code.

Comment: oh really? now I am puzzled... what is this supposed to do? Afaik you can never get `0` from adding something to a pointer

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392057/why-cant-a-constant-pointer-be-a-constant-expression

Comment: GCC 7.x and above compile your code without any errors (with `-std=c++14 -pedantic-errors` flags). Clang and MSVC also don't complain. A GCC 6 bug maybe?

Comment: @user463035818 It doesn't matter whether you compare to 0 or another constexpr string. The code seems to be OK - why doesn't it compile?

Comment: MSVS 2017 compiles your code successfully.

Comment: The current version of GCC is 8.2.  Does GCC 8.2 trip this error?

Comment: erm yes it does matter, `0` is not a constexpr string, it is an integer literal that you compare to the value of a pointer. There is only one pointer with the value `0` ;) and a pointer can never be `0` after adding something to it

Comment: @user463035818 Of course the expression is `false`, OP doesn't argue with that. The question is why it doesn't compile.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yeah, there was a small misunderstanding, in the mean time i got it...(still if this was extracted from real code, I would "fix" that code)

Comment: for grins what if you put spaces around the plus/add?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/oYNZIQ reproduces the error. If you replace `"abcd"` with `&"abcd"[0]`, it works (even inline). It seems that the `const char[]` -> `const char*` decay isn't counted as `constexpr` for whatever reason.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the program has been demonstrated to work on numerous different compilers in the comments, this is just a compiler bug.

Comment: @Barry It's only a compiler bug if the standard requires it to work, which nobody has yet argued as far as I can see.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Alright, I can write an answer I guess - but it's not really going to be interesting.

Comment: The value of `"abcde"` is not known at compile time. It's as simple as that. It isn't known until after link time.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Alright, maybe it'll end up being more interesting than I anticipated?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The restrictions on what can be used in a constant expression are defined mostly as a list of negatives. There's a bunch of things you're not allowed to evaluate ([[expr.const]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.const#2) in C++14) and certain things that values have to result in ([[expr.const]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.const#4) in C++14). This list changes from standard to standard, becoming more permissive with time.

In trying to evaluate:

```
constexpr bool result = (0 == ("abcde"+1));
```

there is nothing that we're not allowed to evaluate, and we don't have any results that we're not allowed to have. No undefined behavior, etc. It's a perfectly valid, if odd, expression. Just one that gcc 6.3 happens to disallow - which is a compiler bug. gcc 7+, clang 3.5+, msvc all compile it.

---

There seems to be a lot of confusion around this question, with many comments suggesting that since the value of a string literal like `"abcde"` is not known until runtime, you cannot do anything with such a pointer during constant evaluation. It's important to explain why this is not true.

Let's start with a declaration like:

```
constexpr char const* p = "abcde";
```

This pointer has *some value*. Let's say `N`. The crucial thing is - just about anything you can do to try to observe `N` *during constant evaluation* would be ill-formed. You cannot [cast it to an integer](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4.14) to read the value. You cannot compare it to [a different, unrelated string<sup>†</sup>](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4.20) (by way of [[expr.rel]/4.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.rel#4.3)):

```
constexpr char const* q = "hello";
p > q; // ill-formed
p <= q; // ill-formed
p != q; // ok, false
```

We can say for sure that `p != q` because wherever it is they point, they are clearly different. But we cannot say which one goes first. Such a comparison is undefined behavior, and undefined behavior [is disallowed](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4.6) in constant expressions.

You can really *only* compare to pointers within the same array:

```
constexpr char const* a = p + 1; // ok
constexpr char const* b = p + 17; // ill-formed
a > p; // ok, true
```

Wherever it is that `p` points to, we *know* that `a` points after it. But we don't need to know `N` to determine this.

As a result, the actual value `N` during constant evaluation is more or less immaterial.

`"abcde"` is... somewhere. `"abcde"+1` points to one later than that, and has the value `"bcde"`. Regardless of where it points, you can compare it to a null pointer (`0` is a null pointer constant) and it is not a null pointer, hence that comparison evaluates as false.

This is a perfectly well-formed constant evaluation, which gcc 6.3 happens to reject.

---

<sup>†</sup>Although we simply state by fiat that `std::less()(p, q)` provides some value that gives a consistent total order at compile time *and* that it gives the same answer at runtime. Which is... an interesting conundrum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please add a reference to the standard which confirms that it's ill-formed to compare p > q?

Comment: We don't actually say that. We only say that the function call operator is `constexpr`, which is approximately meaningless since we don't actually say *for which arguments* it is a constant subexpression.

Comment: @Barry What do you mean by saying that " the value of a string literal like "abcde" is not known until runtime"? I suppose it IS known and e.g. we can compute any substring of it during compile time. Right?

Comment: @embedc I am paraphrasing half a dozen other comments posted across various answers - which suggested that the value of the _pointer_ (the specific address) is not known until runtime. And then I'm explaining why that does not mean that you cannot use the pointer at all.

Comment: Well, by saying "SINCE the value of a string literal like "abcde" is not known until runtime" you made it sound like the value of a string literal like "abcde" is really unknown until compile time.